# There are two event listeners if one is invoked then other should not be invoked

Tags: jquery, event-handling, onchange, jquery-events

There are two event listeners for radio input change event, if change event occurs then the both event listeners are invoked. I want to disable/remove the other event listener if one invoked.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female</label>

$("input:[type='radio']").change(function(){
//first listener
})

$("input:[type='radio']").change(function(){
//second listener
})
```

All I need is, if one listener is invoked then other should not be invoked.

Comment: Why do you need 2 event handlers? and which one should be invoked? on what condition

Comment: Which one should be removed? Better still, don't add that event handler.

Comment: one is common for other pages i cant remove that, and the other one is specific for one page.

Comment: This is why you should be using classes to select elements that have common functionality, not tag names.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan first one should be removed

Comment: @KaleemNalband - Then you can't do it. You'll have to change the order in which they're attached, or better yet, target them more correctly (as Rory suggested).

Comment: In which case call `off()` before attaching the new event handler, but I'd suggest that using classes is still a better solution overall.

Comment: actually i am working on a existing code, and one event handler is in external js(which i want to be removed/diabled) and other i am writhing in the page (inline) which needs to be invoked.

Comment: i solve the problem with setTimeout method to delay the execution of undesired eventhandler's code and with flag, thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female</label>

flag=false;
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
//undesired handler
setTimeout(function(){
if(!flag)
//first handler's code
},300)
})

$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
//desired handler
flag=true;
//
})
```

Comment: That is an atrocious piece of code. No wonder web pages become resource hogs with such nonsensical programming.

Comment: @kuroineko In this particular scenario, the first handler can't be removed since it is required in other pages. and i had to customize the handler only for one page. so i used delay in first handler to confirm that if second handler runs then the first handler should not run. it solves my problem.

Comment: It rather dumps your problem on the computers that will run that code.